# WCF Service custom message inspector

Tags: c#, wcf, xmlhttprequest

I built a WCF Service that uses custom username and password authentication and I am testing it from the client app with the following code:

```
using (ServiceReferenceClient.TestServiceClient tc = new ServiceReferenceClient.TestServiceClient())
{
    tc.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    tc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "User1";
    tc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Pwd1";
    tc.ServiceMethod(param1, param2, param3);
}
```

It works fine but I need to see the actual SOAP request sent to the WCF service and response. How can I do that from my client?

I know I might have to write my own custom message inspector and would like some pointers on how to build one

Comment: You could use a web debugging proxy like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Best practice is to **not** use `using` with WCF clients:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could also use SOAPUI, or even the WCFTestClient (you can see the sent and received XML in the WCFTestClient) as well.

Comment: I cannot use fiddler - in my case it is just not working with the code above. Fiddler just does not show anything

Answer (score 2):

The options mentioned in the comments above are good for testing. If you want something more robust that  you can include in your code, then I think what you want to implement is a [WCF Message Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx).

More on how to do this on the client:

> You can inspect or modify the incoming or outgoing messages across a
>   WCF client by implementing a
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector and inserting
>   it into the client runtime.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786(v=vs.110).aspx

And a good example:

https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector

Comment: Far easier to use WCFTestClient or SOAPUI or Fiddler for testing purposes, IMO.

Comment: SOAP UI and WCF Test client are good for just testing - agreed. The Messasge Inspector option would be something that could possibly aid in non-development  environments - in terms of troubleshooting. I'd want to have all options at my disposal.