# Fiddler not capturing WCF service details in load balancer scenario

Tags: wcf, load-balancing, fiddler

I have some wcf services (say customerservice) hosted in 2 virtual machines VM1 and VM2. They are load balanced using f5 load balancer. Lets call it LB.

The services are consumed from the Web layer using http://LB/customerservice/customerservice.svc. The load balancer routes to either VM1 or VM2 based on its internal logic. I have fiddler running in both VM1 and VM2 but they do not capture anything.

Any idea what might be happening ? Do we need to do anything special for such load balancer scenario.

Pl suggest.

Comment: Besides Fiddler not working for you, are the services in operation and working? Do you need to use Fiddler to examine the details?

Comment: yes the services are working. There are other workarounds to examine details like enabling wcf message diagnostics but i would prefer solutions that does need changing the application's config file. Fiddler is one such solution.

Comment: Got it. I'm not sure what the issue with Fiddler is. As an option, you can use Message Inspectors which do not require config changes. I've answered several posts on Message Inspectors. Perhaps they may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507538/identify-on-which-contract-was-a-wcf-service-called/38513106#38513106 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532833/wcf-service-custom-message-inspector/38533112#38533112

Answer (score 1):

If you want Fiddler to capture the traffic LB sends to your VM1/2 web servicesyou have to configure Fiddler as reverse proxy  -http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy.

Then Fiddler will get the incoming traffic and will forward it to the actual services. If you don't want to change the service configuration then you'd better set Fiddler to run at a different port than the services. In that case, however, you will have to change the LB configuration so that it sends traffic to Fiddler port.