# C# WCF modify SOAP header

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0, soap

I have the following SOAP request came from the client.

```
<e:Envelope xmlns:e="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <e:Header>
        <me:RequestHead xmlns:me="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" >
            <ID>0</ID>
            <Green>
                <a>101</a>
                <b>0</b>
            </Green>
            <Time>1</Tim>
        </me:RequestHead>
    </e:Header>
    <e:Body>
        <m:RequestBody xmlns:m="http://www.my-namespace.org/service/abc">
            <Time>
                <hh>23</hh>
                <mm>59</mm>
                <ss>59</ss>
            </Time>            
        </m:RequestBody>
    </e:Body>
</e:Envelope>
```

In above request there is the `RequestHead` tag, Simply I want to add the new `xmlns` attribute to the `RequestHead` tag before the WCF deserialize the request and convert to the actual parameter of the action method.

**Like this:**

```
<e:Header>
    <me:RequestHead xmlns:me="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" xmlns="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" >
        <ID>0</ID>
        <Green>
            <a>101</a>
            <b>0</b>
        </Green>
        <Time>1</Tim>
    </me:RequestHead>
</e:Header>
```

**So for that I done the following stuff.**

First I implement the **IDispatchMessageFormatter** interface, so we can customize the SOAP envelope before the WCF deserialize it to the actual parameter of the action method.

```
public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
{
    message = new RequestMessage(message);
    this.objMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
}
```

Second I create the my customize message class, which extends the `Message` class, In which I override the `OnWriteStartHeaders` method, where I am trying to add the `xmlns` attribute to the `RequestHead` tag.

```
protected override void OnWriteStartHeaders(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
{
    base.OnWriteStartHeaders(writer);
    writer.WriteXmlnsAttribute("Header", "http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc");
}
```

But this not added the `xmlns` attribute to the `RequestHead`, It adds the `xmlns` attribute to the `Header` tag.

**Actual output:**

```
<e:Header xmlns="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc">
    <me:RequestHead xmlns:me="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" >
        <ID>0</ID>
        <Green>
            <a>101</a>
            <b>0</b>
        </Green>
        <Time>1</Tim>
    </me:RequestHead>
</e:Header>
```

**Output needed:**

```
<e:Header>
    <me:RequestHead xmlns:me="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" xmlns="http://www.my-namespace.org/header/abc" >
        <ID>0</ID>
        <Green>
            <a>101</a>
            <b>0</b>
        </Green>
        <Time>1</Tim>
    </me:RequestHead>
</e:Header>
```

**Problems;**

- So there is any way to add the xmlns attribute to the RequestHead tag ?
- Or we can get the child tag of the Header tag and modify it using the XmlDictionaryWriter ?

Comment: Look into implementing a message inspector. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507538/identify-on-which-contract-was-a-wcf-service-called/38513106#38513106 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532833/wcf-service-custom-message-inspector/38533112#38533112

Comment: @WilliamXifaras, Thanks for you reply, But I can not handle the WCF Client. My client is third party and they are ready to send and receive the SOAP XML. I can do only stuff the WCF Server side. My WCF Server does not able to desieralize  the headers from the SOAP message, If they come with the any prefix. If I remove that prefix so thay can smoothly desieralize. Or If I add the namespace to the <ReqyestHeader> tag with only `xmlns` that it also start to work.